# HighCharts how to make a responsive legend?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, highcharts

I am making a HighCharts pie chart with a responsive legend, the legend should work on mobile views as well as tablet, pc, etc.

Here is sort of a link to my issue on js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sg657bpz/1/

And here are the styles

```
legend: {
          align: 'center',
          layout: 'horizontal',
          width: 600,
          x: 100,
          itemMarginTop: 1,
          itemDistance: 10,
          itemWidth: 170,
        },
```

Basically right now, the legend will just kind of cut the words out of the label when we go to mobile view..

I would like the legend to dynamically shrink in size kind of like how flexbox does, depending on how large your viewport is, so that It fits within the chart and keeps the same structure of having 3 columns and two rows.

How can I add this responsive functionality? In the responsive attribute, it only lets me set one value of either min width or max width, so I cannot do CSS like media queries. Also to create this two row funcitonality, I have to set the width to different numbers, and just kind've guess that It will go on two rows, is there a way to implement this feature easier?

Thank you for the help

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738292/responsive-highchart-legend-position

Comment: Generally, you should use responsive rules and set these sizes for the different window resolution: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules

Comment: I do that, but theres nothing like display: flex; flex-direction: column, or using positioning to move each of the legend items, so I just kinda adjust the width and vertical alignment but its not very customizable, do you have a example?

Comment: You can find such an example in the topic above. Do you mean something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L8b4wg6e/

Comment: not really.. I guess It would be nice If you could try it out on my js fiddle, because the rules that the topic above are using is like align: 'right', vertical:'align', etc. but if you try yourself to make it responsive by adjusting the width and using those basic rules.. you can't get the customization you want, like for example if you want to keep 3 rows and 3 columns of legend items in each viewport, It seems to be impossible with those rules, and I haven't found any examples showing that